# Get the indices along each dimension of a 3D matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Is there a neater way to get the indices along each dimension of a 3D matrix? This is my solution, but I don't like its repeating and taking up three lines.

```
rows   = 1:size(vol,1);
cols   = 1:size(vol,2);
slices = 1:size(vol,3);
```

Comment: [rows cols slices] = size(vol);?

Comment: I want index vectors. It's `1:size(vol,1)`, not just `size(vol,1)`. But I'm hoping there's a solution that looks somewhat like what you posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have various options, but it's not really simpler than what you have.

```
% example volumen
vol = flow(10);

% Option 1
[rows cols slices] = deal( 1:size(vol,1), 1:size(vol,2), 1:size(vol,2) )

% Option 2
indexvectors = cellfun( @(x) 1:size(vol,x), num2cell(1:3), 'uni',0 )

% Option 3
indexvectors = arrayfun( @(x) {1:size(vol,x)}, 1:3)
indexvectors = arrayfun( @(x) {1:x}, size(vol) )
```

The first returns three single vectors and the latter two options return a cell array with a vector for each dimension in each cell.

Comment: Neat, I've been looking for a function like `deal` for a long time! Thanks!

Comment: Given that the matrix is 3D, Option 3 could be even simpler: `arrayfun(@(x){1:x}, size(vol))`